# Accessing an Array element using Scanner Input

Tags: java, arrays

I'm learning to access an element in Arrays using scanner input but when I input the number it gives me the same number I input.

example: Input: 0 then Output 0.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class arrays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
            int[] num = {1,2,3,4,5};
            int i = 0;
            
            System.out.println("Choose an array element: ");
            num[i]= sc.nextInt();
            
            System.out.println(num[i]);
        
    }
}
```

I want to get the output of Array 0 which is 1 but I will end up getting 0 too.

Edit: Now I did

```
int i,n = 0;
i = num[n]=sc.nextInt();
System.out.println(num[i]);
```

It works now when I input 1 it goes to 2 but when I input 0 it still gives me 0 maybe because of the "n = 0"?

**Solved**

**Edit:**
It should be:

```
int n = 0;          
System.out.println("Choose an array element: ");
n = num[sc.nextInt()];
System.out.println(n);
```

is there any other alternative method doing this?

Comment: What *exactly* do you think the line `num[i]= sc.nextInt();` does? Step through your code with the debugger and look at the contents of your array before and after that line.

Comment: I tried doing i = num[n]=sc.nextInt(); but now I can't access the first Array 0